# Acentos en session flash de laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, session

Resulta que estoy enviando mensajes a las vistas, por medio de la clase `Session` y su método `flash` documentación:
[Session->Flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data)

Pero al momento de enviar un acento, en la vista me trae el código como si no tuviera el `utf-8` configurada. Y mi pagina HTML si tiene configurado eso.

Sospecho que es en laravel o en su defecto PHP, que al parecer no esta configurada con utf-8.

Y mi pregunta si alguien sabe cual es la mejor forma de solucionar este problema?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿qué es un asento?

Comment: Lo siento, estaba desesperado cuando realice la pregunta. Corregido la ortografía.

Answer (score 0):

Si el error solo ocurre cuando haces consultas desde tu base de datos revisa que el collation de tu base de datos y sus tablas estén en `utf-8`.

También en el archivo *database.php* debes tener configurado el `utf-8` :

`'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],`

Otra opción también podría ser utilizar la función de php [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php).

También revisa que esté todo bien escrito aveces se nos puede pasar por alto una letra.

Por ultimo, revisa que tu editor de texto este configurado en utf-8.

Comment: No, el error no de DB, porque no hago nada con la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que es muy tarde ya, pero expongo cómo lo tengo yo hecho por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Yo uso un fichero llamado `mensajes.php` que que devuelve un array con los mensajes:

```
<?php
return [
    ...
    "borradoExito" => "El registro ha sido borrado con éxito"
    ...
]
```

Luego hago referencia al mensaje, con el método `flash()` así:

```
$request->session()->flash('mensajes.borrardoExito');
```

He de comentar que realmente no sé si tiene algo que ver pero el fichero `database.php` lo tengo configurado así:

```
...
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
...
```

Y sí salen los acentos que pongo en la cadena de texto del array